# Unusually large ViewState in Sandbox - debugging?

Tags: managed-package, sandbox, viewstate

We have a VF page that in package/dev orgs (full of data) give around 40kb View State, well within the limit of 135kb.

In one sandbox, though, where the managed package is installed, the page gives a View State error of 305kb.  It's strange because this is a sandbox without any data the page is supposed to show.

I would like to see what this View State is composed of, and enabled Developed Mode and Show View State in Development Mode in My Personal Information.  However, this only seems to work in the dev org; enabling it in the Sandbox does not give me the bottom menu (and I tried in all browsers).  Therefore, I have no idea of why this spike is being caused.  I checked the Limits class but it only seems to refer to Apex, not VF limits.

Comment: Did you see the actual viewstate tab, did you enable the view state in development mode and see where the actual spike is occurring?

Comment: There is no tab at all.  When I do the same in the package org, it shows up fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I enabled logging through the LMA org and found the HEAP_ALLOCATE lines in the debug log.

There, it was obvious that the problem was the number of users in the system, which was several times greater than the number in other orgs.

I still don't know why View State Development Mode didn't work though.